# Does Perl v5.10.1 have memory leaks or how to interpret valgrind

Tags: perl, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have a script that has memory leaks. I believe this is so because after I perform `undef` on my nested objects, the amount of memory in script is unchanged. I have used [Devel::Cycle](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Cycle/) to locate any cyclical references and I have turned those cyclical references into weak references with `Scalar::Util`. The problem still remains.

Now I am trying to use Valgrind to solve the issue. As a first start with valgrind, I tested things out a perl hello world program:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Hello world!\n";
```

Here was the valgrind output when running `valgrind --trace-children=yes perl ./hello_world.pl`:

```
==12823== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12823==     in use at exit: 290,774 bytes in 2,372 blocks
==12823==   total heap usage: 5,159 allocs, 2,787 frees, 478,873 bytes allocated
==12823==
==12823== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12823==    definitely lost: 13,981 bytes in 18 blocks
==12823==    indirectly lost: 276,793 bytes in 2,354 blocks
==12823==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12823==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12823==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12823== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==12823==
==12823== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12823== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

My understanding, from [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/valgrind.html), is that when the number of `allocs` does not equal the number of `frees` you have a memory leak.

Since all I'm doing is printing hello world, I'm forced to ask the question, does the Perl interpreter itself, here v5.10.1, have at least its own memory leak or am I interpreting things all wrong?

I would like to understand this before I tackle my actual perl script.

**ADDENDUM**

I see in [Perl 5.12.0 delta](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5120delta.html#Selected-Bug-Fixes), the following:

> A weak reference to a hash would leak. This was affecting DBI [RT #56908].

This may ultimately apply to my complete perl script, and not this hello world program, but it's leading me to think that I should go through the pain of installing the latest version of perl as non-root.

**ADDENDUM2**

I installed activestate perl 5.16.3, and the problem, and also my actual script's problems, still remains.

I suspect that in the case of this hello world program, I must be using/interpreting valgrind improperly but I don't understand where yet.

**UPDATE1**
Daxim's answer does make a difference. When I introduce the following line in my perl script:

```
use Perl::Destruct::Level level => 1;
```

Then the valgrind output is:

```
==29719== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29719==     in use at exit: 1,617 bytes in 6 blocks
==29719==   total heap usage: 6,499 allocs, 6,493 frees, 585,389 bytes allocated
==29719==
==29719== LEAK SUMMARY:
==29719==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29719==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29719==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29719==    still reachable: 1,617 bytes in 6 blocks
==29719==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29719== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==29719==
==29719== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==29719== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Which is a substantial difference. My own memory leak problems with my script remain but at least this hello world program now seems sensible to valgrind.

This whole thing though begs the question, what is the point of stopping hard cyclical references with `Scalar::Util` if no memory is freed until the program exits, baring the use of this somewhat esoteric `Perl::Destruct::Level` module???

Answer (score 4):

The leak is intentional. [vincent in #p5p](http://irc.perl.org) comments:

> Allocated memory isn't actually released unless [PERL_DESTRUCT_LEVEL](http://p3rl.org/perlhacktips#PERL_DESTRUCT_LEVEL) is set because it's faster to let the operating system handle this. PERL_DESTRUCT_LEVEL is only available for debugging builds or by using [Perl::Destruct::Level](http://p3rl.org/Perl%3a%3aDestruct%3a%3aLevel) from perl.

Comment: Then how does one use valgrind to distinguish this from leaks in the user's script? Also, doesn't this mean that memory can not be released during a perl script - that it's memory consumption can only grow and never shrink during execution?

Comment: You are invited to follow the hyperlinks in my post in order to peruse the fine documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it (and please correct me if I'm wrong — I haven't read the code, and the documentation seems pretty scant), the point is that, in a typical Perl program, there's a lot of stuff that will be allocated but that won't be freed before the program ends.  This includes things like global variables, but also, for example, the compiled program code itself.

Now, perl *could* free the memory used for all that stuff when the program ends, but it turns out that there's usually not much point, since the OS will do it anyway.  One exception is when something like valgrind is looking to see if there's any unfreed memory left at the end of the program, and assuming that any such memory must've been leaked.

So, basically, perl is normally lazy and won't bother freeing memory when it knows it's just about to exit and let the OS take care of it.  Setting PERL_DESTRUCT_LEVEL tells perl to clean up that memory anyway, just to show tools like valgrind that it wasn't actually leaked.

Anyway, none of this, AFAIK, affects memory management *during* program execution.  If you reduce the reference count of something to zero while you're program is running (e.g. by letting a variable go out of scope, or by directly overwriting the last reference), it's going to get freed, regardless of PERL_DESTRUCT_LEVEL.

However, note that this typically only frees the memory for perl itself to reuse — aside from some rare cases like explicit mmap(), it's quite unusual for *any* program running on a modern OS with virtual memory to actually release memory pages back to the OS while it's running.