# Perl script strange behavior / Reclaim memory

Tags: linux, perl, hash, operating-system, swap

My script does the following

1. Reads a huge text file and creates a hash from it.(About 24million simple key value-pairs.Takes about 5 minutes and consumes 92% of the 4Gb computer memory)
2. Runs a simulation using information from hash.(Takes about 30minutes)
3. Prints the results at the end of the simulation(to a file and stdout)

Then it waits for 10+ minutes after the last print statement and exits. The wait at the end doesn't happen every time. During the wait `top` command shows the same 92% memory usage but no cpu usage. Why does it wait sometimes after it is done ?  If I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, it exits immediately without any change in outcome(results). How do I debug this or is it expected behavior as the hash is huge ?

**EDIT**

Is it possible to reclaim some memory on the fly by deleting unwanted key - value pairs from the hash ?

Comment: Much of your problem slowless might be due to swapping. The time spent at the end might be due to destruction of your data structure. `POSIX::_exit(0)` will bypass cleanup.

Comment: If I bypass cleanup won't the OS reclaim the memory ? Is it a good practice ? If I run it on a system with more memory will this issue disappear ?

Comment: The OS will reclaim memory. It's not good practice, as destructors won't get called. Yes, if it's a swapping issue as I'm guessing.

Comment: Have you looked at how much swap space the process uses while running?  You can do this with ps or top.  You can also use free to monitor system wide swap usage.

Comment: #1 makes me think you're reading the entire file into memory all at once in order to hash it. That's in general a Really Bad Idea(tm)... Read it in manageable chunks using a single buffer instead - that alone can drastically reduce your memory footprint...

Comment: twalberg - I am looking up several 10s of thousands of key value pairs without any predictable order. I can only chunk it if I can establish a pattern in the accesses.

Comment: @Jean Ah... well, that's quite a bit different than "Reads a huge text file and creates a hash from it"... Although it now occurs to me by "hash" you may be talking about the associative array data structure, not a cryptographic hash like MD5/SHA1/etc., which is the way I originally read the question...

Comment: Is it possible to reclaim some memory on the fly by deleting unwanted key - value pairs from the hash ?

Comment: Sometimes to get a feel for whats happening, if on Linux I do a ps -ef & then sudo strace -p<pid> -s128 it may (or may not) give an idea of what its up to.

Comment: As Ian said you debug this using strace. It is not quite easy to analyze strace's output so I blogged how to do it: http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Strace#Analyzing_strace.27s_output Also I would paste the perl script here and add debugging output ("hello world") just before the end of the program to find whether this will be printed. This will guide us further if you post it here.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know 'delete' function (so removed reference to perldoc -f delete :)

For the memory debugging you could use valgrind
Also this hint can be helpful: [Does Perl v5.10.1 have memory leaks or how to interpret valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055491/does-perl-v5-10-1-have-memory-leaks-or-how-to-interpret-valgrind)
It suggests using:

use Perl::Destruct::Level level => 1;